# react native fetch not sending body content

Tags: react-native

I am new to fetch in react native and followed [this tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html).
I am trying to send a json body to an private api server, I checked the server log and found out that the body content is empty.

Here is the code in react native

```
authenticateLogIn(){
    fetch('<URL>', {
          method: 'POST',
          header: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify({'username': '<username>', 'password':'<password>'})
        })
        .then((incoming) => incoming.json())
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.header);
          Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(response.body));
        })
        .done();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe because it shoueld be header**s**? (with the s)

Comment: Ahh that was it, always thought it was just ONE header not without S

Comment: you are right, when remove s it pass as post method , but still data passed to back end empty

Answer (score 1):

It might be because your JSON body isn't being parsed correctly. `bodyParser` https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser is part of the middleware that parses request bodies and needs to be configured.

`req.body` kept coming back empty for me until I added `app.use(bodyParser.json()` into `server.js` file. Make sure you import `body-parser`.

Comment: Feel so dumb that I missed this, but this was it! Thanks!

Comment: Hello, can you help in similar issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302135