# The body parameters are not working in fetch post react native

Tags: api, react-native

I have a post request from react native app to chragebee for creating new customer, in postman it works fine, and in the app it works fine also, but the problem is in passing the body parameters from the app to chargebee, so i can not see for example the body parameters in the response body return from chargebee like the email, firstname, lastname , .... after creating user from the app, whereas in postman i can see them.

[The postman post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Spf4.png)

[The response in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fmdM.png)

[The response in postman if i remove the body parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXh2e.png)

The function responsible for signup process in react native :

```
export const ChargebeeCreateUser = (first_name,last_name,email) => {

   const bodyParams = {
      first_name: first_name,
     last_name:last_name,
      email:email,
   };

  return fetch(`https://editpress-test.chargebee.com/api/v2/customers`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encode('site_api_key'),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify(bodyParams)
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {

 return responseJson
    })
}
```

Calling the function:

```
register = async () => {
  const { given_name,family_name,email, password } = this.state
  let ChargebeeCreateUserResponse = await 
  ChargebeeCreateUser(given_name,family_name,email);
  console.log(ChargebeeCreateUserResponse);
---
---
---
```

[The result of console.log(ChargebeeCreateUserResponse):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6Gi9.png)

Comment: In your postman request the content type is `x-www-form-urlencoded`, while in react-native you specify `application/json`, and send stringyfied json object.

Comment: I tried:   var formBody = [];
         var details={
              'first_name':first_name,
              'last_name':last_name ,
              'email':email
         };
         for (var property in details) {
               var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
               var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
               formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
         }
  formBody = formBody.join("&");

Comment: then body:formBody

Comment: have you tried to send parameters with FormData()?

Comment: ok i will try it

Comment: no it never works also